# How to use a the toggle button multiple times efficiently?

Tags: javascript, css, toggle

I have the following page, which is behaving exactly how I want it to.

However, I know the page can be written more efficiently in two ways:

1. First and most importantly, I am repeating a javascript function. This is to denote which text should be expanded when its specific button is clicked, but I know the two can be written as one since they share the same type of functionality.
2. Second, the css is clumsy. I've used `!important` to override whether text is shown or hidden.

Can someone please suggest the most eloquent rendition of this page?

Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.expand-button {
    background-color: #1860ac;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 15px auto 40px auto;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.very-hidden {
    display: none!important;
}
.mystyle {
    display: block!important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>
    First Paragraph
</h2> 
<button class="expand-button" id="b1" onclick="expand1()">Read more</button>
<span class="hidden" id="myDIV1"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu magna vitae ipsum dignissim euismod. Curabitur egestas congue elit vitae accumsan. Integer aliquet dictum est, vitae placerat arcu dapibus commodo. Quisque nec libero sed urna tristique mattis sed vel lacus. Praesent ut justo eget elit mattis suscipit. Curabitur ut libero eros. Morbi nec viverra velit. Suspendisse at nulla quis purus luctus laoreet. Nunc euismod ultricies quam vitae mattis. Fusce auctor urna at libero dapibus, sed sollicitudin ex facilisis. Maecenas ultricies nisl sodales lectus ultricies volutpat. Sed pretium turpis vitae dui tincidunt, ac sagittis ante efficitur.</p>
</span>
<h2>
Second Paragraph
</h2>
<button class="expand-button" id="b2" onclick="expand2()">Read more</button>
<span class="hidden" id="myDIV2">
<p>Nunc porttitor, quam vel consectetur feugiat, ipsum justo accumsan urna, non egestas ante ipsum in tellus. Maecenas pretium, velit dictum ultricies convallis, neque justo aliquet dolor, sed tincidunt massa ipsum at justo. Integer auctor auctor pretium. Ut in lacus ex. Suspendisse id placerat sapien, sed placerat dui. Curabitur eget malesuada arcu. Nam fringilla imperdiet mauris, at malesuada dolor tempor sit amet. Nam feugiat mi vel accumsan tristique. Curabitur imperdiet mollis mi vel consequat. Nam sollicitudin, elit sit amet tincidunt consectetur, sapien elit blandit lorem, at semper ipsum enim eget eros. Cras in ultrices dolor. Maecenas a lacus risus. Duis sed leo id est ultricies rhoncus ac sed ex. Fusce commodo consectetur nunc, sed lacinia sem.
</p>
</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
function expand1() {
   var element = document.getElementById("myDIV1");
   element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
   var element = document.getElementById("b1");
   element.classList.toggle("very-hidden");
}
function expand2() {
   var element = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
   element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
    var element = document.getElementById("b2");
   element.classList.toggle("very-hidden");
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use the same `class` to hidde the elements, and use the same function passing a variable with the number of the `div` you are clicking, so you can so you can build the `id` name of the `button` and the `div`.

```js
function expand(number) {
  var id = 'myDIV'+ number
   var divElement = document.getElementById(id);
   divElement.classList.toggle("mystyle");
   var idButton = 'b'+ number
   var button = document.getElementById(idButton);
   button.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

```css
.expand-button {
    background-color: #1860ac;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 15px auto 40px auto;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.mystyle {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
<h2>
    First Paragraph
</h2> 
<button class="expand-button" id="b1" onclick="expand('1')">Read more</button>
<span class="hidden" id="myDIV1"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu magna vitae ipsum dignissim euismod. Curabitur egestas congue elit vitae accumsan. Integer aliquet dictum est, vitae placerat arcu dapibus commodo. Quisque nec libero sed urna tristique mattis sed vel lacus. Praesent ut justo eget elit mattis suscipit. Curabitur ut libero eros. Morbi nec viverra velit. Suspendisse at nulla quis purus luctus laoreet. Nunc euismod ultricies quam vitae mattis. Fusce auctor urna at libero dapibus, sed sollicitudin ex facilisis. Maecenas ultricies nisl sodales lectus ultricies volutpat. Sed pretium turpis vitae dui tincidunt, ac sagittis ante efficitur.</p>
</span>
<h2>
Second Paragraph
</h2>
<button class="expand-button" id="b2" onclick="expand('2')">Read more</button>
<span class="hidden" id="myDIV2">
<p>Nunc porttitor, quam vel consectetur feugiat, ipsum justo accumsan urna, non egestas ante ipsum in tellus. Maecenas pretium, velit dictum ultricies convallis, neque justo aliquet dolor, sed tincidunt massa ipsum at justo. Integer auctor auctor pretium. Ut in lacus ex. Suspendisse id placerat sapien, sed placerat dui. Curabitur eget malesuada arcu. Nam fringilla imperdiet mauris, at malesuada dolor tempor sit amet. Nam feugiat mi vel accumsan tristique. Curabitur imperdiet mollis mi vel consequat. Nam sollicitudin, elit sit amet tincidunt consectetur, sapien elit blandit lorem, at semper ipsum enim eget eros. Cras in ultrices dolor. Maecenas a lacus risus. Duis sed leo id est ultricies rhoncus ac sed ex. Fusce commodo consectetur nunc, sed lacinia sem.
</p>
</span>

</body>
```

Hope this help you :)